# Generate SQL query from Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, sql-query-store

I have connected my SQL database (based on a star schema design) to Power BI in order to build dashboards. However, I have to write (test) SQL queries now that would create the same results as in my Power BI dashboards.

Does Power BI automatically generate such queries or is there a program with which I can generate SQL queries out of a Power BI dashboard? In general, how do I write queries that give the same results as the Power BI dashboard that I have designed?

Comment: You can use SQL Server's XEvents to see the raw SQL that PowerBI is running against your database, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16). It's a simple, standard tool from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (Tools -> SQL Server Profiler). You can connect to SQL Server to get a trace log with all actions/queries on your server.

Also, Microsoft counts Profiler as a deprecated tool and suggests that you use [Extended events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of it. But Profiler is still working.